# How will I get this commandGAteway exception get solved?

Tags: axon, axon-framework

I am creating a delete command and am getting this error

```
org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.command.AxonServerRemoteCommandHandlingException: An exception was thrown by the remote message handling component: OUT_OF_RANGE: [AXONIQ-2000] Invalid sequence number 0 for aggregate "ef734cce-fb22-4bb1-a68a-8c8c6c7924e9", expected 1
```

The request am giving in postman is DELETE -> http://localhost:8081/products
body has a String "ef734cce-fb22-4bb1-a68a-8c8c6c7924e9" and in my backend I have file `Controller` with :

```java
@DeleteMapping()
public String deleteProduct(@RequestBody String productId1) {
    //create the command
    DeleteProductCommand deleteProductCommand = new DeleteProductCommand (productId1);
    String result = commandGateway.sendAndWait(deleteProductCommand);
    return result;
}


@Data
@Builder
public class DeleteProductCommand {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private String productId;
    
    public DeleteProductCommand(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
}


@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(ProductDeletedEvent event) {
    this.productId = event.getProductId();
}

@EventHandler
public void on(ProductDeletedEvent event) {
    productRepository.deleteById(event.getProductId());
}
```

I was expecting it to delete the said product with the passed id.

But when I pass it directly, it gets deleted, I think the error is in somewhere like the event handler or something. At times am getting the product id as json

Comment: You wrote: "in my backend I have file Controller with ..." Does that mean you have the rest controller and the event handling component in the same class?

Comment: The code snippet you've shared, @Law, is a bit too minimal to deduce the exact predicament.
So, if you could please share the entire Aggregate (the class handling your commands) and not just the event sourcing handlers, we can better assist you.